# limit lightbox to screen size

Tags: size, lightbox

I must be missing something but does anyone know a way of restricting lightbox images to screen size. I'm using jts with lightbox v2.05 which can be viewed here:
http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jts/with_lightbox/ (jquery thumbnail Scroller)

css

```
#lightbox{  position: absolute; left: 0; width: 100%; z-index: 100; text-align: center; line-height: 0;}
#lightbox img{ width: auto; height: auto;}
#lightbox a img{ border: none; }

#outerImageContainer{ position: relative; background-color: #fff; width: 250px; height: 250px; margin: 0 auto; }
#imageContainer{ padding: 10px; }

#loading{ position: absolute; top: 40%; left: 0%; height: 25%; width: 100%; text-align: center; line-height: 0; }
#hoverNav{ position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index: 10; }
#imageContainer>#hoverNav{ left: 0;}
#hoverNav a{ outline: none;}

#prevLink, #nextLink{ width: 49%; height: 100%; background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,AAAA); /* Trick IE into showing hover */ display: block; }
#prevLink { left: 0; float: left;}
#nextLink { right: 0; float: right;}
#prevLink:hover, #prevLink:visited:hover { background: url(../images/prevlabel.gif) left 15% no-repeat; }
#nextLink:hover, #nextLink:visited:hover { background: url(../images/nextlabel.gif) right 15% no-repeat; }

#imageDataContainer{ font: 10px Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; background-color: #fff; margin: 0 auto; line-height: 1.4em; overflow: auto; width: 100% ; }

#imageData{ padding:0 10px; color: #666; }
#imageData #imageDetails{ width: 70%; float: left; text-align: left; }  
#imageData #caption{ font-weight: bold; }
#imageData #numberDisplay{ display: block; clear: left; padding-bottom: 1.0em;  }           
#imageData #bottomNavClose{ width: 66px; float: right;  padding-bottom: 0.7em; outline: none;}      

#overlay{ position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 90; width: 100%; height: 500px; background-color: #000; }
```

Comment: You can probably find it in the CSS.

Comment: I'm not sure what to change...any ideas? I've added the css above.

Answer (score 2):

Not saying it is perfect, but it works.

in `"objImagePreloader.onload = function()"` before  `"_resize_container_image_box(objImage"` 
 put below code
 in lightbox css put `"#lightbox-image{ width: 100%; }"`

```
var imageAspect = objImagePreloader.width / objImagePreloader.height;
if(objImagePreloader.width>$(window).width()){
  objImagePreloader.width = $(window).width();
  objImagePreloader.height = objImagePreloader.width / imageAspect;
}

if(objImagePreloader.height>$(window).height()){
  objImagePreloader.height = $(window).height()*0.85;
  objImagePreloader.width = objImagePreloader.height * imageAspect;
}
```